# css-loader import is not working properly

Tags: webpack, postcss, css-loader

I am using Webpack to create bundles for my react application. I am using `postcss` and `css-loader` to load CSS files. In my app, css import is not working properly. I am trying to import every thing in my `Main.css` file, but webpack throws error by saying:

```
./node_modules/css-loader?{"importLoaders":1,"modules":true,"minimize":{"calc":true,"colormin":true,"core":true,"discardDuplicates":true,"discardOverridden":true,"mergeLonghand":true,"minifyFontValues":true,"minifyParams":true,"normalizeCharset":true,"orderedValues":true,"reduceDisplayValues":true,"styleCache":true,"uniqueSelectors":true,"convertValues":true,"discardComments":true,"discardEmpty":true,"discardUnused":true,"filterPlugins":true,"mergeIdents":true,"mergeRules":true,"minifySelectors":true,"normalizeString":true,"normalizeUrl":true,"reduceBackgroundRepeat":true,"reduceTransforms":true},"sourceMap":true,"camelCase":true,"localIdentName":"[path][name]---[local]---[hash : base64 : 5]"}!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib!./app/styles/main.css
    Module build failed: Error: Failed to find 'vendor/reset'
        in [ 
            /Users/bharat/Documents/redmart-repo/Partner-Portal-V2/app/styles
        ]
        at /Users/bharat/Documents/redmart-repo/Partner-Portal-V2/node_modules/postcss-import/lib/resolve-id.js:48:11
     @ ./app/styles/main.css 4:14-133 18:2-22:4 19:20-139
     @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8081 webpack/hot/dev-server ./app/styles/main.css
```

Here is the webpack configs to load CSS([full config link](https://gist.github.com/iiison/184edf00ff01da15b9f3905b2790d555#file-webpack-config-babel-js)):

```
{
    test    : /\.css$/,
    exclude : /node_modules/,
    include : `${PATHS.styles}/`,
    use     : [
        {
          'loader' : 'style-loader'
        },
        {
          'loader'  : 'css-loader',
          options   : {
            importLoaders  : 1,
            modules        : true,
            minimize       : cssNanoConfigs,
            sourceMap      : !isProd,
            camelCase      : true,
            localIdentName : '[path][name]---[local]---[hash : base64 : 5]'
          }
        },
        {
          loader : 'postcss-loader'
        }
      ]
    }
```

Here is the [link to postcss config file](https://gist.github.com/iiison/184edf00ff01da15b9f3905b2790d555#file-postcss-config-css)

Directory structure of my app is:

- app/

  - js/
  - styles/

    - base/

      - _base.css
      - _reset.css
      - _variables.css
    - vendor/

      - _reset.css
    - main.css

Answer (score 0):

Currently the postcss-loader does not support auto-resolving import statements with missing underscore characters. (See this github issue for further details: https://github.com/postcss/postcss-import/issues/145)

To address this, you can either change the import statement to:

```
@import "vendor/_reset";
```

Or check out the library [postcss-easy-import](https://github.com/TrySound/postcss-easy-import) - it supports resolving imports to include leading underscores.